# Using sass with Antd and CRA

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, antd

I am trying to integrate SASS with antd and CRA. I followed many tutorials but most of them were created years back and all of them throw some error.

Somehow I found an article which is working fine [link](https://dailyjsx.com/antd-rescript-sass-boilerplate/)

But I am worried that above solution is a hacky way of integrating SASS, so some day it may stop working.

Is there a simple way of integrating SASS in antd with CRA ? Has anyone did it before ? Or any pointers how it can be done.

Note : Since I am all time CRA fan I dont have much experience with webpack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not sure what you mean with integrating sass in antd. You can use sass with node-sass dependency. No matter if you are using antd, which uses its own classes. You just need to create a style.scss on your component and play with styles. Maybe you mean to integrate with webpack?

Comment: Actually I was looking for a solution which will allow me to use antd's LESS color variables but that seems too complicated and not trustworthy. So I think I will go with not using that.